# Is it possible to connect a GitHub repo with a Vercel Project without opening a browser?

Tags: vercel, github-cli

Assuming I have:

- GitHub and Vercel accounts already setup,
- Am using **GitHub CLI** and **Vercel CLI**

Is it possible to connect a GitHub repo with a Vercel Project without opening the browser?

I know I can create a GitHub remote repo with:

```bash
gh repo create --source=. --public --remote=origin --push
```

And then, deploy to Vercel via the interactive CLI:

```bash
vercel
```

But I still have to open the browser and manually click the **Connect Git Repository** button in Vercel.

Am I missing something or can this *not* be done entirely via the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

[`vercel git connect`](https://vercel.com/docs/cli/git)

> The `vercel git` command is used to manage a Git provider repository for
> a Vercel Project, enabling deployments to Vercel through Git.
>
> When run, Vercel CLI searches for a local `.git` config file containing
> at least one remote URL. If found, you can connect it to the Vercel
> Project linked to your directory.

---

Complete steps:

```
$ gh repo create # (Add a remote? Yes)
$ vercel
$ vercel git connect
```